# Remove Subfigures from List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats

I'm using `\subfloat` and `\subref` to put 40 sub-figures into a few large figures. This is clogging up my List of Figures at the beginning of my published document.

[image: output]

How do I remove references to subfigures in the List of Figures?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I deleted my answer in wait for the MWE already requested by Werner.

Answer (score 8):

I found this burred in my header file

```
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
```

A quick change to:

```
\usepackage[lofdepth=1,lotdepth]{subfig}
```

Solved the problem.