# Exclude subfigures from the table of figures in latex

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing my thesis in latex and I have a lot of figures and subfigures. I looked everywhere online but I couldn't find how to exclude the subfigures from the table of figures. Below it's a part of the code where I input some subfigures and the relevant packages I'm using. Note that in the main document I want to have a common caption for the two subfigures and have only A and B appear below the two subfigures. I manage to do that with the code I have below. But in the table of figures I want to see only the number and the common caption for the 2 subfigures. Now in the table of figures I see the caption of the main figure and below is just the number of the 2 subfifures. I hope I made my question clear. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,width=8cm,height=5cm]{subfigure1.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:subfig1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,width=8cm,height=5cm]{subfigure2.png} 
    \caption{} 
    \label{fig:subfig2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[This is the caption for both subfigures that I want to appear in the table of figures]{}
    \label{fig:fig1}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: since there is no compilable `MWE` to begin with, may be this could be something to start with: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118930/remove-subfigures-from-list-of-figures

Comment: if it helped you, may be you can check the tick-mark in the answer (top-left side and below the voting pane). its also better to accept the answer of your previous questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `list=true` if you do not want sub-figures to be listed in the List of Figures.

Also, there are many ways you could improve your current code:

1. You need to write `\end{subfigure}%` for your first `\end{subfigure}`, to suppress an unwanted space between the two sub-figures.
2. Your specifications of the width and height should be modified: Keep only one of the three `width=\linewidth`, `width=8cm` and `height=5cm`.
3. The syntax of `\caption` is

   ```
   \caption[short caption text]{very long very long very long caption text}
   ```

   where the stuff in the square brackets is *optional*.